# UTF-8 coding in Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have an UTF-8 character encoded with `_' in between, e.g., '_ea_b4_80'. 
I'm trying to convert it into UTF-8 character using replace method, but I can't get the correct encoding.

This is a code example:

```
import sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

r = '_ea_b4_80'
r2 = '\xea\xb4\x80'

r = r.replace('_', '\\x')
print r
print r.encode("utf-8")
print r2
```

In this example, r is not the same as r2; this is an output.

```
\xea\xb4\x80
\xea\xb4\x80
관  <-- correctly shown
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\x` is only meaningful in string literals, you're can't use `replace` to add it.

To get your desired result, convert to bytes, then decode:

```
import binascii

r = '_ea_b4_80'

rhexonly = r.replace('_', '')          # Returns 'eab480'
rbytes = binascii.unhexlify(rhexonly)  # Returns b'\xea\xb4\x80'
rtext = rbytes.decode('utf-8')         # Returns '관' (unicode if Py2, str Py3)
print(rtext)
```

which should get you `관` as you desire.

If you're using modern Py3, you can avoid the import (assuming `r` is in fact a `str`; `bytes.fromhex`, unlike `binascii.hexlify`, only take `str` inputs, not `bytes` inputs) using the `bytes.fromhex` class method in place of `binascii.unhexlify`:

```
rbytes = bytes.fromhex(rhexonly)  # Returns b'\xea\xb4\x80'
```